# How to fix JSHint warning when I use the "Lazy Function Definition" pattern?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I use the "Lazy Function Definition" pattern to define *global* functions like so:

```
if (bArmingSequenceComplete () ) {
    console.log ("Good to go.");
}
// Code flows from high level to low level and support functions...
// vvvvv

function bArmingSequenceComplete () {
    //  In reality this is a long, complicated series of tests that only need to be done once.
    var gtg = true;  

    if (gtg) {
        bArmingSequenceComplete  = function () { return true; };
    }
    else {
        bArmingSequenceComplete  = function () { return false; };
    }

    return bArmingSequenceComplete ();
}
```

This works flawlessly and the overall code is easy to grok.
I like this pattern because it's very efficient AND it's clear as to what it's doing.

But JSHint gives me warnings like:

> Reassignment of 'bArmingSequenceComplete', which is is a function. Use 'var' or 'let' to declare bindings that may change.

After diving into [some JSHint source code](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/ea6f361939bea5583d4f8c03044e352134938b9e/src/messages.js), I found that this is controlled by the `W021` option. So I can squelch it like:

```
    // jshint -W021
    if (gtg) {
        bArmingSequenceComplete  = function () { return true; };
    }
    else {
        bArmingSequenceComplete  = function () { return false; };
    }
    // jshint +W021
```

**But, is JSHint telling me something useful?  Is it really a mistake to define such functions?**

**Can I disable all such warnings globally without also losing the general "Reassignment" check?**

---

The suggestions to use `let` or `var` make for ***worse*** code (violates "Most important at top" rule and/or completely fails).

For example:

```
if (bArmingSequenceComplete () ) {
    console.log ("Good to go.");
}

// Code flows from high level to low level and support functions...
// vvvvv

let bArmingSequenceComplete = function  () {
...
```

Fails with:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: bArmingSequenceComplete is not defined

---

And:

```
if (bArmingSequenceComplete () ) {
    console.log ("Good to go.");
}

// Code flows from high level to low level and support functions...
// vvvvv

var bArmingSequenceComplete = function  () {
...
```

Fails with:

> Uncaught TypeError: bArmingSequenceComplete is not a function

---

Defining the function before use, violates the boss's "most important or high-level up top" rule.

Comment: change first line to `let bArmingSequenceComplete = function () {`

Comment: @JaromandaX, turns out that doesn't work well.  See the updated question.

Comment: use var not let?

Comment: @JaromandaX, Fails with "is not a function". See the last code block.

Comment: Why not use `IIFE` pattern here?

Comment: Late comment, but rather than reassigning the function, which is a code smell, might you keep a persistent variable the function can see, and on call, return that variable if it exists, otherwise run the expensive procedure (once) and reassign that persistent variable? Disadvantage is that if you want the result to be encapsulated in the function, you'll have to create its scope in advance https://jsfiddle.net/1put6ks9/

Comment: Thanks, @CertainPerformance, that's a possibility, but I don't like breaking encapsulation. Anyway, I've since switched to a better validator than JSHint -- which may be the best answer to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, Using the `IIFE` pattern can come in handy in your case. EG:

```
let bArmingSequenceComplete = (function () {
    let gtg = true;
    let outputMethod = null;
    if (gtg) {
        outputMethod = () => { return true; };
    } else {
        outputMethod = () => { return false; };
    }
    return outputMethod;
})();

if(bArmingSequenceComplete()) {
    console.log('good to go');
}
```

**Update:**

Since there are 2 conditions you need:

- Define high-level code at the top
- Define support/helper methods at bottom

So let's try it this way:

```
function startHighLevelCode() {
    if(bArmingSequenceComplete()) {
        console.log('good to go');
    }
}

let bArmingSequenceComplete = function () {
    let gtg = true;
    let outputMethod = null;
    if (gtg) {
        outputMethod = () => { return true; };
    } else {
        outputMethod = () => { return false; };
    }
    bArmingSequenceComplete = outputMethod;
    return bArmingSequenceComplete();
};

// After all support functions
startHighLevelCode();
```

Comment: Thanks, guleria, but notice that this buries the "high level" code (EG: `if(bArmingSequenceComplete(...`) underneath all the support functions.

Comment: Also, it fires the very expensive `bArmingSequenceComplete()` code whether it needs it or not.

Comment: @BrockAdams I updated the answer. Have a look if this satisfies your criteria. It is a workaround but looks good I think.

Comment: My bad I had forgotten the `return bArmingSequenceComplete();` at the end of `bArmingSequenceComplete` method. Updated it.